# El nombre de la columna es invalido C# WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

Hace poco comencé a estudiar un poco de `C#` en `WPF` pero me ha surgido un pequeño inconveniente y es el siguiente:

Intento ingresar un registro en una base de datos SQL pero me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

> El nombre de la columna 'Durazno' no es valido.

Sucede que quiero ingresar un registro que contenga `Codigo, Producto y Fecha` pero al intentar ingresar la cadena de caracteres en el campo `Producto` me sale el mensaje con el error mencionado arriba, intento ingresar la palabra **durazno**.

Algo que me desconcierta es que si intento ingresar un numero si me lo permite sin arrojar el mensaje. Agrego el código que realiza la sentencia SQL. En el combobox (cmbProducto) es donde estoy intentando ingresar la cadena de caracteres.

La sentencia SQL está bien formulada ya que la probé en el `SSMS` y no dio error alguno.

```
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand();
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comando.CommandText = "INSERT BD_PRUEBAS.dbo.BD_DATOS (Codigo,Fecha,Producto) VALUES (" + txtCodigo.Text + ",GETDATE()," + cmbPoducto.Text + "); ";
        comando.Connection = conexion;
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Espero sus comentarios. De verdad que no he dado con el problema y por ende con una solución. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En columnas donde quieras introducir texto debes añadir en la query ese texto entre comillas simples para indicarle al SQL que eso es un texto, te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
comando.CommandText = "INSERT BD_PRUEBAS.dbo.BD_DATOS (Codigo,Fecha,Producto) 
    VALUES (" + txtCodigo.Text + ",GETDATE(),'" + cmbPoducto.Text + "'); ";
```

Como sugerencia, intenta siempre usar [parámetros de SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8) y no poner el contenido de un control *a saco* en la consulta SQL, para evitar de esta forma la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Comment: Gracias Marc, te lo agradezco mucho. En cuanto a los parametros para este ejercicio me lo pedian hacer de esta manera y bueno no recordaba bien las comillas.